# ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing

Tags: oracle

I have a query that is working on oracle 12c but not in 10g. I am not sure what the problem is:
My query is:

```
WITH tab1(rn,begin_chq_num,chq_lvs_stat,chq_num_of_lvs,tes) AS
  (SELECT 1 rn,
    begin_chq_num,
    chq_lvs_stat,
    chq_num_of_lvs,
    SUBSTR(chq_lvs_stat,1,1) tes
  FROM tbaadm.chq_book_table
  WHERE del_flg != 'Y'
  AND acid      IN
    (SELECT acid
    FROM tbaadm.GENERAL_ACCT_MAST_TABLE
    WHERE foracid = '01411110171546'
    )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rn + 1 rn,
    begin_chq_num,
    chq_lvs_stat,
    chq_num_of_lvs,
    SUBSTR(chq_lvs_stat,rn + 1,1) tes
  FROM tab1
  WHERE rn < chq_num_of_lvs
  )
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN begin_chq_num = 1
    THEN rn
    ELSE begin_chq_num +(rn-1)
  END cheque_num,
  begin_chq_num
  ||'-'
  ||(chq_num_of_lvs+begin_chq_num-1) cheque_range,
  DECODE(tes, 'I', 'Issued', 'P', 'Cleared', 'U', 'Unused', 'S', 'Stopped', 'C', 'Cautioned', 'D', 'Destroyed', 'R', 'Returned Paid', 'T', 'Transfered') status
FROM tab1
ORDER BY chq_lvs_stat,
  rn;
```

The error is :

```
ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing
32033. 00000 -  "unsupported column aliasing"
*Cause:    column aliasing in WITH clause is not supported yet
*Action:   specify aliasing in defintion subquery and retry
```

What should I do different?

Comment: `FROM tab1` ... this looks like a recursive CTE and it could be the cause of the error.  Make sure your version of Oracle supports this, and if so, that your syntax be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle 10g, the [sub-query factoring clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) does not support column aliases or recursive sub-queries. The syntax you are using appears in [11gR2](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142).

You need to change:

```
WITH tab1(rn,begin_chq_num,chq_lvs_stat,chq_num_of_lvs,tes) AS
```

To:

```
WITH tab1 AS
```

And find a different solution that does not use a recursive subquery factoring clause.

I think you could do this in Oracle 10g:

```
WITH tab1 AS (
  SELECT l.COLUMN_VALUE rn,
         begin_chq_num,
         chq_lvs_stat,
         chq_num_of_lvs,
         SUBSTR(chq_lvs_stat,l.COLUMN_VALUE,1) tes
  FROM   tbaadm.chq_book_table t,
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT LEVEL
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( t.chq_lvs_stat )
             )
             AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
           )
         ) l
  WHERE  del_flg != 'Y'
  AND    acid IN ( SELECT acid
                   FROM   tbaadm.GENERAL_ACCT_MAST_TABLE
                   WHERE  foracid = '01411110171546'
                 )
)
SELECT CASE
         WHEN begin_chq_num = 1
         THEN rn
         ELSE begin_chq_num +(rn-1)
       END cheque_num,
       begin_chq_num
         ||'-'
         ||(chq_num_of_lvs+begin_chq_num-1) cheque_range,
       DECODE(
         tes,
         'I', 'Issued',
         'P', 'Cleared',
         'U', 'Unused',
         'S', 'Stopped',
         'C', 'Cautioned',
         'D', 'Destroyed',
         'R', 'Returned Paid',
         'T', 'Transfered'
       ) status
FROM   tab1
ORDER BY chq_lvs_stat, rn;
```

Comment: Now when I remove that part I am getting another complain about recursion: `ORA-32031: illegal reference of a query name in WITH clause
32031. 00000 -  "illegal reference of a query name in WITH clause"
*Cause:    forward or recursive reference of a query name in WITH clause is not
           allowed.`